# Requirements not installed in a python virtual environment

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-venv, pyenv

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL, I have installed python 3.7.17 with pyenv.
If I run `$HOME/.pyenv/versions/3.7.17/bin/python -m venv $HOME/virtualenv/websites/web/myproject` it correctly creates a virtual environment using python 3.7.17 .
I can activate the virtual env and if I run `$HOME/virtualenv/websites/web/myproject/bin/python3 -m pip list` it shows me only pip and setuptools. The problem is that if I run `$HOME/virtualenv/websites/web/myproject/bin/python3 -m pip install -r ./my/github/repo/requirements.txt` (after cloning the repo) it says that it's installing the requirements somewhere but if re-run the pip list command it doesn't show them. The strange thing is that they aren't installed globally. Strangely if I run `$HOME/virtualenv/websites/web/myproject/bin/python3 -m pip install requests==2.xx.x` it correctly install it, and i can see the requests module using pip list. Anyway the question is, what am I doing wrong? How can I install the requirements?

More info, as asked in the comments:
In the requirements there are some packages, like:

```
Django==2.2
requests==2.10
```

and others, it's just a regular requirements.txt

The output of the pip install -r requirements.txt:

```
Requirements already satisfied: Django==2.2 in ./lib/python3.7/site-packages (from -r ./mygithub/repo/requirements.txt)
```

and similar lines

Edit: if I run `pip install package==x.y` it works, I can see the package being installed in the virtual environment, but if I run `pip install -r requirements` it doesn't install anything.

Comment: We really can't say, with the information you have provided. What's in `./my/github/repo/requirements.txt` and what's the output when you run `pip install -r ./my/github/repo/requirements.txt`?

Comment: @tripleee more info added, feel free to ask more details

Comment: what OS you're using ?

Comment: @AhmedYasin I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, on a WSL (Windows 11)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `virtualenv` for this purpose. Use following commands to do so.

step 1: `sudo pip install virtualenv`

step 2 : Go to you project directory.

step 3 : `virtualenv myenv`

step 4 : `source myenv/bin/activate`

step 5 : `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Then you're good to go.
I'm assuming you have alreadt python and pip on your system.

Comment: Really thanks for the good and clear answer but.. there is a solution without installing virtualenv? Other people are working on this and probably they were able to install requirements.txt while using the python built-in venv. I really prefer a solution using venv.

Comment: Why do you think switching to `virtualenv` will resolve whatever problem the OP is trying to solve?